# Additive masking for encryption inside $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: encryption

If I have to obfuscate my value $m$ from someone, then what is wrong with just showing them $m+r$ as an "encryption" of $m$.
If someone would try to guess $m$ from it then it would require them to brute force till the upper bound of the value $m+r$ since $r$ and $m$ both can be anything in [0, $m+r$]. So, if I make this value $m+r$ to be really large so that this range [0, $m+r$] becomes computationally infeasible to brute through, doesn't this ensure the security of my secret value $m$?
I understand that this violates the property of succinctness which is required from all encryptions, but I don't see any potential attack here which can reveal the value $m$ and which performs better than just doing an exhaustive search.
Now my question is that if an adversary has $m_1 + r_1$ and $m_2+r_2$ such that he knows that $m_1 > m_2$ and $r_1 > r_2$, then can he infer something about he input values of $m_1$ and $m_2$?

Comment: If you picked a particular sub-group of $\mathbb Z$ like $\mathbb Z_n$ (ie all numbers reduced modulo n), then this would be equivalent in security to the one-time pad.

Comment: But what if I just use \mathbb{Z}, isn't it secure then?

Comment: The proof requires the key-elements to be chosen uniformly at random from the set. You can't do that with infinite sets. (BTW use code like `\mathbb{Z}` as `$\mathbb{Z}$` so it gets rendered when using the browser)